# How can I see the current bandwidth use of the dedicated graphics memory?

Tags: memory, performance, graphics, gpu, monitoring

Can I calculate it using the values I see on gpu-z? can it actually be calculated or monitored?

Comment: Run http://download2-developer.amd.com/amd/GPU/executables/PCIeSpeedTest_v0.2.zip

Comment: It won't be realtime, but it will give you an opportunity to see the bandwidth when stress tested, and allow you to figure if everything is working ok.